# freebase not working in python

Tags: freebase

Im trying to run freebase using python on Ubuntu 12.10 the first time. here's what i did

```
import freebase
query = {
"id" :   "/en/the_beatles",
"type" : "/music/artist",
"album" : [{
    "name" :         None,
    "release_date" : None,
    "track": {
        "return" : "count"
    },
    "sort" : "release_date"
}]
```

}

```
freebase.mqlread(query)
```

Here's that error i got

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.8-py2.7.egg/freebase/api/session.py", line 597, in mqlread
    r = self._httpreq_json(service, 'POST', form=dict(query=qstr))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.8-py2.7.egg/freebase/api/session.py", line 420, in _httpreq_json
    resp, body = self._httpreq(*args, **kws)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.8-py2.7.egg/freebase/api/session.py", line 406, in _httpreq
    return self._http_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.8-py2.7.egg/freebase/api/httpclients.py", line 66, in **call**
    self.log.error('SOCKET FAILURE: %s', e.fp.read())
AttributeError: 'error' object has no attribute 'fp'

Could anyone help me resolve this?

Thansk in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the old Python client library it won't work because Google never migrated it to work with the new APIs.  You'll need to use the standard Google APIs Python library and the discovery interface.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started

Comment: Tom i followed the tutorial on the link you sent me but when i run the same codes. i got this httplib.ResponseNotReady